# Word Problem - what percent of the women who apply are hired?

Tags: problem-solving, percentages, word-problem

At a certain factory, twice as many men as women apply for work. If 5% of the people who apply are hired and 3% of the men who apply are hired, what percent of the women who apply are hired?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand the question... I have been trying to solve the Word problems for days but only few i did, there are 35 WPs i need to solve. My word problem solving skill is not good.

Comment: Why you need from us to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to write equations. For example, number of men applying is $m$, number of women applying is $w$, then $m=2w$. Continue with the other quantities

Comment: Start with this: if $x$ people applied for work, how many were hired? Can  you write an expression for this number?

Comment: You might try it with numbers first to get a feel for it.  What if $100$ women apply for work?

Answer (score 1):

Two thirds are men of which $3\%$ apply and hired, that makes $2\%$ of all.  As $5\%$ are hired this leaves $3\%$ of all which are women and hired.  Hence the percentage of women getting hired is $\frac{3\%}{1/3}=9\%$.

Comment: U did it directly. I solved it through Equation: 0.03m + x(m/2) = 0.05(m+m/2)
And x = 9%.

Comment: Right: in this case Algebra isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

$$300\%\cdot5\%=15\%\\15\%-6\%=9\%$$ 9% of women are hired. All I did was convert total population into women popultation equivalents. Then did the math in those.

Answer (score -1):

Work through these:

- Total number applied:  $x$
- Number of men applied: $m(x)$
- Number of women applied:  $w(x)$
- Total number hired:  $h(x)$
- Total number of women hired:  $h_w(x)$
- Total number of men hired:  $h_m(x)$

[image]

Comment: m = number of men apply for work.
m/2 = number of women apply for work.
5℅ = people hired
3% = men are hired 
2% = women are hired

Equation:
0.03m + 0.02(m/2) = 0.05

......Am i correct?

Comment: So far yes... but you have a few more steps....

Comment: I did it -->> Equation: 0.03m + x(m/2) = 0.05(m+m/2)
And n = 9%. Thank you . It is hard for me to understand the Question.

Comment: @Askani:  You might find that drawing a picture helps.  (See my amended solution.)